Using an AND gate to control CD4053 switching
I have a design where I use two momentary switches to turn two different circuits on or off, but I'd also like to be able to use an AND gate to allow turning a third circuit on or off by simultaneously pressing both momentary switches. Here is the schematic of what I have breadboarded so far:

(EDIT: Click the image to enlarge it.) This circuit works on a 0V-9V supply (with 4.5V as the VREF). The momentary switches being used are Normally Open (making contact between the leads when the buttons are pressed).
For the sake of clarity I have omitted the associated components with channels A and B. The way the circuit works is pressing either switch turns either circuit on or off (Switch 2 is the main bypass control here, and Switch 1 changes another path), and the BAT41 diode is there to make sure that the blue side of the red/blue LED does not stay illuminated when Switch 2 is not engaged (the LED will flash red or blue in time with the LFO when the entire circuit is on, but not when it is in bypass, so you know if the circuit is "on" or not). This circuit works just fine, and I have implemented it in a couple of designs over the years.
What I would like to do from here is use the transistor AND gate on the left side of the schematic to enable a third choice, labelled as Switch 3, by using both actions from Switch 1 and Switch 2. However, I have not had any success with this implementation, and wonder if there is perhaps something I am missing?
On the bottom left of the schematic you will see that one of the Schmitt triggers from the 40106 is used as a clock oscillator (included to show that it is being used), and I have a spare Schmitt trigger oscillator available if needed.
I realize that using an AND gate in this way can and will result in both Switch 1 and Switch 2 changing states from where they may currently be, and this is fine, though it would also be nice to figure out a way to maintain their state when using the AND gate (some sort of additional RC delay on the switches, perhaps?)
So, what am I missing? Is the AND gate not the correct implementation, and I should in fact be using a NAND gate configuration? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Where is the problem? Describe.  What happened when both switches are On?

What it should do is switch (Switch 3) the Input (tag on the bottom left of the CD4053) from Input 1 to Input 2 when both buttons are pressed, but it just reads that as regular action for Switch 1 and Switch 2.
